# 500 (Internal Server Error) angular Delete api

Tags: angular, typescript, api

I get the 500 (Internal Server Error) when i press the delete button which calls the delete funtion, i want to delete the data from server,  how do it pass the index and delete the todo

```js
> import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
>     import { Router } from '@angular/router';
>     import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormArray } from '@angular/forms';
>     import { Validators } from '@angular/forms';
>     import { HttpService } from '../http.service';
> 
> 
> 
>     @Component({
>       selector: 'todo-app',
>       templateUrl: './todo-app.component.html',
>       styleUrls: ['./todo-app.component.css']
>     })
>     export class TodoAppComponent implements OnInit {
> 
>     myForm: FormGroup;
>     todoitems = [];
>     todolist;
>     submitted = false;
>     name;
> 
>       constructor(private router: Router, private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private httpService: HttpService ) {
>       }
> 
>       ngOnInit() {
>         this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
>            todoitems : [this.todolist, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)])]
> 
>         });
>         
>         this.httpService.gettodo().subscribe(
>           (data:any[]) => {
>             this.todoitems = data;
>             console.log(this.name);
>             }
>         );
>       
>     }
>       
> 
> 
>       
>       
> 
>       addTodo(todolist) {
>         
>         if (this.myForm.invalid) {
>           this.submitted = true;
> 
>          
>        }
>         if (this.myForm.valid) {
>           var body = { name: this.todolist }
>          this.httpService.addTodoo(body).subscribe(
>           (data:any) => {
>             this.todoitems = data;
>             console.log(data);
>           }
>         )
> 
>           this.myForm.reset();
>           this.submitted = false;
>           console.log('Form Submitted!');
>           console.log(this.todoitems);
>             
>       }     
> 
>       }
> 
>       deletetodo(id : number) {
>         this.httpService.deleteTodo(id).subscribe()
> 
>     }
> 
> 
> 
>     }
> 
> 
> //http.service delete fun
>  deleteTodo(id){
>     return this.http.delete('http://localhost:3000/api/names/=${id}')   }
> 
> 
>
```

```html
> 
>     <form [formGroup]="myForm">
> 
>         <div>
> 
>             <input formControlName="todoitems"  [(ngModel)]="todolist" name="todoitems">
>             <button  type="submit" (click)="addTodo(todolist)">Add</button>
>                 <div>
>                 <div *ngIf="submitted && myForm.controls.todoitems.errors">
>                     <div *ngIf="myForm.controls.todoitems.errors.required"> please fill</div>
>                     <div *ngIf="myForm.controls.todoitems.errors.minlength">min 3</div>
>                 </div>
> 
>             </div>
>         </div>
>     <br>
>                <div>
>             <table style="width:50%">
>             <tr *ngFor="let todoitem of todoitems; let i = index" >
>              
>                 <td>{{ todoitem.name }}</td>
> 
>              <td>
>                     <button (click)="deletetodo(id)">Delete</button>
>              </td>
> 
>             </tr>
> 
>          </table>
>         </div>
> 
>     </form>
> 
>
```

Comment: Please add your httpService for get help. Your issue could comme from your backend. Have you try to call it without angular ?

Comment: i have added the delele function from http.service file, check the edited code @MartinChoraine

Comment: i want to send the index of the item i'm delelting, how do i do it ? @charlietfl

Answer (score 1):

`500 Internal Server Error` means your server is the one having issues, not your angular application.

It could be that you are calling your endpoint with an Http method that isn't supported by your server, you are passing the wrong informations to it, or simply that the method on your server is bugged.

Comment: You are right. Response status 500 means have some issue on server side code.

Comment: app.delete('/api/names/:id', (req , res) => {

    const index = names.indexOf(name);
    names.splice(index ,1 );
    res.send(names);




});  this is the code

Answer (score 0):

Try update your delete http :

```
deleteTodo(id) {
    return this.http.delete(`http://localhost:3000/api/names/${id}`)  
}
```

It seems you used quote instead of backquote needed to eval `${id}`

Then your uri is `api/names/=${id}`. `=` symbol really needed by your back or just a typo ?

Then in your template update :

```
 <button (click)="deletetodo(todoitem.id)">Delete</button>
```

Comment: HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 500, statusText: "Internal Server Error", url: "http://localhost:3000/api/names/:undefined", ok: false getting this error

Comment: app.delete('/api/names/:id', (req , res) => {

    const index = names.indexOf(name);
    names.splice(index ,1 );
    res.send(names);




}); is there any error in this ?

Comment: You have another issue in your template. Check edited anwser